# Error while loading RTextTools library in Mac

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

Error while loading RTextTools library in Mac, however this works for windows pc.

Here is the error:

```
library(RTextTools)  #  For removeSparseTerms()
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lava’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RTextTools’
```

I have tried installing RTextTools via:

```
install.packages("RTextTools")
```

and

```
install.packages("RTextTools", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", 
                 dependencies=TRUE)
```

and

```
install.packages("RTextTools", repos=c("http://rstudio.org/_packages", 
                 "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("lava")`, then retrying?

Comment: It worked ...thanks a lot !